# What are the consequences of violating a one-to-many relationship & when to use a many-to-many?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework

Considering the amount of order records are many magnitudes larger then tags:

[image]

1. I’ve read a SO question’s comment where inserting order# 68 as pictured wouldn’t cause any trouble but if I wanted to query orders by certain tags, a many-to-many is more appropriate/convenient/efficient since otherwise in a one-to-many every single order will have to be checked to know how its tags, is this true?

   - a.    I also recall having read that many-to-many relationships cost the most in resources and don’t perform well yet also read claims that the performance losses are negligible and not worth the risk and overhead of handling orphan records of many-to-many relationships, any comments?
   - b.    Based on other readings I was convinced to model a many-to-many via making 2 one-to-many tables with a joint table of FKs, if there is no longer a many-to-many but 2 one-to-many tables are the aforementioned cons of many-to-many avoided?
2. In a similar question I’ve posted in another forum I was told that I couldn’t even insert order# 68 and doing so would cause referential integrity issues, which nearly doesn’t make sense, is this also true?

I want to rid myself of the conflicting and auto contradictory posts I’ve read.

Comment: @leo I uploaded it for you.

Comment: just to make it clear: only if you normalize, you will need a join table for a many-to-many relationship. In 2nd NF you could just a easily with a lot of redundancy in your database. To the matter of the question: You can insert any record that will not conflict with your table- and referential constraints (PK, FK, UNIQUE...). A relationship suggests a FK constraint is in place, which would forbid inserting other orders with already in place tagIds. However, not all databases have FK constraints (though they do speed things up, as FK columns are mostly indexed)

Comment: I recommend normalizing your tables and setup foreign keys. Its the only way you can be really sure your data never gets corrupted and it saves you a lot of coding because you dont have to check yourself if an insert, update or delete is following the rules, the database can do . this much faster than you can. Your point b is correct, that is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The world is a complex place and your questions assume there is one answer to all questions.  In fact for the the questions you ask the answer is one to many.

1. The insert you describe *could* cause a problem, or it *could not* cause a problem.  This depends on if you added rules to your database to enforce referential integrity.  Some people like to do such things -- I don't.  I have a data model that says that a relationship is 1 to many and I assume people will follow it because it will break if they don't.  Making the database enforce this rule just slows things down.  In my opinion it is better to have everything break once a year, track down the problem, flog the new programmer with a wet noodle and move on.

As for the rest of 1. this just depends on what makes sense for the data you are working with -- Who can say in the general case.

2. See 1.  Yes it is possible to have the database stop you from the insert, but I don't advise setting up your databases in this way.  UNLESS Order# is an index that is defined as unique -- in that case it would give an error when the duplicate insert was attempted.

Comment: Having no FK in your database will only lead to a corrupt database, I would not advise this. What if you delete a record in a table where the primary key is referenced in another table ? Either your database is now corrupt or you have to overflow your code with checks for this. Let the database do this that is where its for. The programmer should not be tracked down, the database designer should be.

Comment: @Hogan   what would be most performant to find "order #s" of "sales" tag: 1. inner join of OP pictured one-to-many   or 2. join of the many-to-many join table?

Comment: without a FK you cannot do inner join because the record you are refering to might not be there anymore.

Comment: @GuidoG your saying the record stands risk of being deleted EVEN IF there aren't any constraints as alluded to by Hogan and I assume you would also suggest the only option is option 2. in my 1st comment 8 minutes ago to Hogan??

Comment: I  am saying that if you do not setup foreign keys you can delete all records in the tag table without errors and then all references in your order table are corrupted because they reference non existing records in the tag table

Comment: @GuidoG with EF a navigation property (FK) always shows so please assume that yes there are FK's, and also consider their aren't any constraints.  A. That considered, do all records in tag table still get deleted or any other abnormalities with OP pictured relationship?   B. would your inner join be more performant for the comparable many-to-many or OP one-to-many?

Comment: If the FK are present in the database than yes inner joins will be more performant because it can use index searching in stead of full table scans in the query plan.

Comment: @GuidoG - your comments are all over the place and contradict each other.  I stand by my statements after having worked with large database systems for over 20 years.  For example I have one database system I work with that ingests 5 million records a day and has a couple of billion on disk.  How exactly would it be able to do anything if it had to do referential checks on every record ingested?  There are 4-5 foreign relationships per record.    You do the math.

Comment: @SeanPrice the performance depends mostly on what indexes are defined.  the 1 to many or many to one or many to many has almost no effect compare to that.

Comment: @Hogan I have the same years experience with the same amount of data and I have never had any troubles with performance using FK. The only problems where encountered where there are no FK used (corrupt data). Also my comments are not all over the place and where do the contradict ? show me one

Comment: @GuidoG - "without a FK you cannot do inner join" - not true FK is not required to do an inner joing.  "Having no FK in your database will only lead to a corrupt" - not true. "If the FK are present in the database than yes inner joins will be more performant because it can use index searching" - not true a FK constraint has nothing to do with index searching, having an index allows for the performance boost of indexes.

Comment: @Hogan without a FK an inner join is dangerous because the record you are joining to might not exist anymore and then the record from your left table is omitted from the result. Surely with  your years of experience you know that dont you ? Without a FK you can delete a record that is referenced by another table which makes your database corrrupt, Surely with  your years of experience you know that dont you ?

Comment: @GuidoG - don't use an inner join then use a left join.  Your idea of "dangerous" makes no sense to me... SQL works as SQL works.  If you are worried about your data model not having integrity then it might make sense to put a monitor in to test it every so often.  Having the DB server test it on every insert on every table will have a performance impact.

Comment: @Hogan Yes SQL works as SQL works that is not the problem. But the database also works as the database works. The whole reason databases like SQL Server, Oracle, and so on exists is because they can do referential integrity. And they do it very well. There is absolutely no impact at all in your performance when setting up the correct FK. That is what databases do and you should make use of it in stead of inventing the wheel again.

Comment: @Hogan By the way, if you are so worried about performance than you should avoid left joins and use inner joins wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image I would say that you have a one to many relationship between tblTAG and tblOrder.
I dont see a many to many relationship in this image and adding the records will not produce any problems at all.

tblTAG.TagID 1 can exists as many times in tblORDER as you want without problems.
Also a query like

```
select * from tblORDER where TagID = 1
```

will perform very fast because the foreign key in tblORDER will have created an index.

So why exactly do need a many to many relationship here ?

Comment: tagID 1 would be associated to both order 23 & order 68, (which is greater then 1 order, though modeled as a #one# to many, in essence the tags is associated to 2 orders).  In general I've read tags are typically modeled as many-to-many which is why I used this example but considering your pretty open in your db relationship decisions and are a seasoned db person, the million dollar question now is in which cases does @GuidoG use a many-to-many where a one-to-many variant wouldn't suffice, without sacrificing referential integrity and having the FK named explicitly as constraints?

Comment: I use a many-to-many where the normalization told me to use one, it has nothing to do with a one-to-many not being suffice. If each record in your order table needs to reference a tag from the tags table than there is no need for a many-ot-many. Unless I am mistaken that is what I can make up from the image in your question. So my question is what do you need. Every order referencing a tag ? that is a one-to-many from tag to order and a one-to-one from order to tag. Its not clear to me what you need in your table design.

Comment: In the image in your question the 1 and the many symbols seem to be on the wrong side to me, unless I have understood it wrong. If so please elaborate

Comment: this whole discussion for me at his point is based on the notion that once 2 tag associations for record 68 are inserted this no longer is a one-to-many, and the many is in effect on BOTH sides, i.e. the "sales" tag is associated to 2 orders (#23 & 68) and orders are associated to 2 tags (sale & deliv),,, in the absence of a (Pk | orderid | tagid) many-to-many join table

Comment: not exactly true. You have to look at it differently, From an order point of view ONE order will have just ONE tag, from a tag point of view ONE tag exists in MANY orders. So it is a one to many relation from tag to order and a one to one relation from order to tag. There is no need for a many to many here Unless I misunderstood your table design

Comment: when you would add another record in order, 5, 68, 1 so there are 2 orders with the same orderid and the same tagid, then you will have a many to many because than it is impossible to find only one order starting from tag. Since I can not see this in your image I assume it is not possible to add 2 orders with exact the same orderid and tagid ?

Comment: well if thats so then unless I'm mistaken the only way a many-to-many exists is as marketting/jargon/feature hype until a single record's fk property can contain multiple values at a db record level, which doesn't happen, meaning ALL records are ALWAYS related as a combination of either one-to-one's and/or one-to-many's regardless as to what a graphic model depicts

Comment: yes there is a difference to what marketing ppl call many to many and what db ppl call it. The only way to create a many to many is by a link table where both other tables have a one to many relation on. If your order table can have records with duplicate orderid and tagid than you need a link table that liks the id of that table, because with these duplicate values you cannot uniquely identify an order record anymore

Comment: I couldn't edit previous comment in time,,, well if thats so then unless I'm mistaken the only way a many-to-many exists is as marketting/jargon/feature hype until a single record's fk property can contain multiple values at a db record level, which doesn't happen, meaning ALL records are ALWAYS related as a combination of either (*actual*) one-to-one's and/or one-to-many's (*in perspective*) regardless as to what a graphic model depicts,,, to drill further down into the same concept, its all just a bunch of one-to-one's which constitute a one-to-many, the many-to-many, it's a unicorn

Comment: yes you cannot have a many to many direct between 2 tables. This is because it will be impossible to uniquely identify records using the relation. So that is why a link table is needed. In some graphic designs the link table is not shown but whoever has to create it in the db will have to do it this way.

Comment: In the example in your image you do not need a many to many, unless it is possible to have 2 orders with the same orderid an tagid